# Instagram API The access_token provided is invalid

Tags: javascript, instagram-api

I am a new programmer and quite new to `.js` in general.
My current issue is that when I run this script `Instagram.popular(function(r){ console.log(r)})` locally (i.e. on the console of Firefox) I get the following error `The access_token provided is invalid`

As I read in gitHub and other places, it has something do with Instagram changing some API policy as discussed [here](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/349). The change log for Instagram is given [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I will very much appreciate it.

Below you can see my full `.js` code.

**CODE**

```
    window.Instagram = {
        /**
         * Store application settings
         */
        config: {},

        BASE_URL: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1',

        init: function( opt ) {
            opt = opt || {};

            this.config.client_id = opt.client_id;
        },

        /**
         * Get a list of popular media.
         */
        popular: function( callback ) {
            var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/media/popular?client_id=' + this.config.client_id;
            this.getJSON( endpoint, callback );
        },

        /**
         * Get a list of recently tagged media.
         */
        tagsByName: function( name, callback ) {
            var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/tags/' + name + '/media/recent?client_id=' + this.config.client_id;
            this.getJSON( endpoint, callback );
        },

        getJSON: function( url, callback ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function( response ) {
                    if ( typeof callback === 'function' ) callback( response );
                }
            });
        }
    };

    Instagram.init({
        client_id: '97bf259cc45f4dd6a2cd02b694b7ffe7'
    });


    $( document ).ready(function() {

        Instagram.popular(function( response ) {
            var $instagram = $( '#instagram' );
            for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++ ) {
                imageUrl = response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url;
                $instagram.append( '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" />' );
            }
        });

        $( '#form' ).on('submit', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var tagName = $( '#search' ).val();
            Instagram.tagsByName(tagName, function( response ) {
                var $instagram = $( '#instagram' );
                    $instagram.html('');

                for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++ ) {
                    imageUrl = response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url;
                    $instagram.append( '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" />' );
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should start from is by hitting [Instagram popular](https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=97bf259cc45f4dd6a2cd02b694b7ffe7) link in the browser. you will notice that you are getting invalid access token in response as well. This is happening because instagram API requires authentication which is done through [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/). You have to find a js implementation of OAuth or a 3rd party js liberary with OAuth implementation and use it to obtain access token and use to get resources in subsequent server calls. you should also reference [Instagram Developers website](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) as well to see how they suggest implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using some old code that uses `client_id` to make API calls.

Instagram stopped allowing API calls with just `client_id` since June 1, 2016. Now you have to have an `access_token` in URL param to make API calls, you have to do the oauth authentication and get `access_token` as described in documentation:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

And also from your code `/media/popular/` is not valid anymore, its a deprecated, looks like you are using some old Instagram library